# Appearance of HTML and CSS snippet is changing when it is indented

Tags: bug, code-formatting, stack-snippets, code-block

Today I was editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72921576) to change the formatting of its code into a runnable snippet. Once I configured the snippet, Stack Overflow would not let me submit my question because it thought that the question had code that was improperly formatted, even though this was not the case. After pressing ctrl + "K" to justify the content, the HTML and CSS code block changed in appearance from
[image: HTML and CSS code]

To

[image]

Please may you inform me why this is happening, and how I can circumvent this bug?

Comment: I am unable to repro this change.. I also don't see the text `sif150` anywhere in the question...

Comment: Every time I made an edit to the body of the post before submitting my edit, the number after the sif in the <pre> tag kept increasing by two... I do not know why this is

Comment: Do you have any userscripts/ extensions installed that ma be doing this?

Comment: I do not think so... I think it may have been caused by indenting a code snippet twice, but this seemed to be the only way to make it allow me to submit my edit.

Comment: That buggy behaviour is documented by the community in a few places, though I don't know of a staff response about it. Some threads here on MSE [How do I force Stack Snippets to render as a code block?](/q/358977), [Indenting interactive interpreter invokes interesting interactions](/q/377561).

Comment: And on MSO: [Bug (?) with stack-snippets within three backticks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406027/15497888), [Stack Snippets delimiters are being parsed too eagerly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284254/15497888), [Snippets comments are incorrectly parsed inside code blocks producing strange output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310537/15497888)

Comment: Generally the issue is that the Stack Snippet is over-indented or inside code fences which causes some parsing issues. I've taken the liberty of [updating your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/72921576/2) to use a Stack Snippet without the formatting errors.